# Get location of other people in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm developing an Android app that tracks a **number** of people through GPS with their legal consents.

For some reason, I can't seem to find any related topics in Google or maybe I just can't construct the right words.

Google Maps and others are already setup. I only need the approximated `LatLng`s and some basic infos from those people in-track.

Where do I start? or any recommended links?

Answer (score 3):

If you're tracking multiple people with their consent, then I'm assuming that your app is running for each of the users on their individual device(s). If that's the case, use the Android geolocation API to get the device's LatLong and publish it to a backend on the cloud periodically (say every minute or so to avoid too many writes to the backend). You can use a key/value storage to store the coordinates, where the keys are the user identifiers, and the value is the last lat/long (I'd also suggest storing a timestamp for the last update to allow for identifying stale data).

You can then query/subscribe to the backend to retrieve the last lat/long of (a) specific user(s), and then use it to create a custom marker on the GMap API.

We're working on a platform that uses a similar logic but for a different use-case, calculating proximity to specific locations and providing actions based on the proximity.

I hope this helps. We're using Ionic/Angular for our build platform so we're using PhoneGap API's to access the GeoLocation services of the device.

Comment: Would you recommend me using Google's servers to upload my data because they have a quota 100request / 24hrs w/c is something inadequate in my part but, I don't want to purchase their `Geolocation API for business license` or I set up my own through free-hosting sites?

Comment: You can't use the GeoLocation API to store your own information. You need to use a different service to store the data. You can a Backend-as-a-Service like Parse or Firebase to store and retrieve the data. Google doesn't have a ready to use BaaS engine, but you can build one using AppEngine if you need it. The link in RIT's comment is a good start.

Comment: Ashwin Shankar's would be accepted as the correct answer. You've asked a start, he gave you much more than that. Please be kind and respect the time and work of another people. Tomorrow this can happen to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can do below things,

If the two uses have the same application, they should push their location (obtained from the Cell ID or GPS) to a Web Server (which you will handle). You can then exchange the location coordinates using your web-service.

For reference, have a look at this link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms980225.aspx#v35go_topic2

Another the thing which I want to recommend you why don't you try to do this using google+ apis. Little googling will help you.

Comment: I think you have not gone through that link that's why you posted this thing. Doesn't matter there are people link you who are not good readers